# HTTP Authorization Rule in htaccess- convert to Nginx

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, slim

I have recently moved my application from Apache to Nginx server. We have written
API's in Slim framework. So to enhance the basic security of API we have written token (static) based authentication(if-else loop) logic.

Below rule was added in .htaccess on the apache server which was working fine.

SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1

Now since we have moved to Nginx so above .htaccess rule will not work.

What changes do i need to make in Nginx config to get the above thing working.

It would be great if someone can explain the process step by step.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following to your Nginx configuration.

```
fastcgi_pass_header Authorization;
```